# Is the set $\{\phi+\phi':\phi\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})\}$ dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuously differentiable functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$.   I'm wondering whether the statement in the title is true. Does anyone know of techniques to prove similar statements? I don't have any direction right now.

Comment: Define all the terms used in the question.

Comment: @Daron I think "dense" and "L^2" is clear. I added the definition of $C^1_c$.

Comment: But what is $\phi'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of proof.

1. $C_c^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^2$.
2. Given $f \in C_c^{\infty}$, there exists $f_n \in C_c^{\infty}$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and
   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)e^x dx = 0.$$
   Hint: Let $f_n = f + g_n$, where $g_n$ is supported on $[n, \infty)$.
3. Let
   $$\phi_n(x) = e^{-x} \int_{-\infty}^x f_n(t) e^t dt.$$
   Then $\phi_n \in C_n^1$ while $\phi_n + \phi_n' = f_n$.